# Best approach to Independently Timing each Tick of a For Loop in another Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, timeout, thread-safety

Suppose I have a client thread and a server thread. The client thread must perform an expensive for loop operation which is prone to hanging. Thus, the server has independently determine whether each tick of the for loop has exceeded the max time. The context behind this is that the server will timeout the client if it takes too long to complete a tick.

My initial idea below is to have two for loops in the client and server thread. The server thread will have a condition variable that waits for 1 second. If the client does not notify the condition variable in 1 second every tick, the server will time it out:

Server

```
 bool success;
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(CLIENT_MUTEX);
     success = CLIENT_CV.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::seconds(1));
     if (!success) {
         std::cout << "timed out during tick " << i << std::endl;
         break;
     }
  }
```

Client

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(CLIENT_MUTEX);

    //do work

    CLIENT_CV.notify_one();
}
```

However my implementation attempt is unreliable and times out at random times given the same work for the client. How can I improve the design to make it more reliable?

Side Note:

A simple solution to this would be for the server to time the entire for loop as opposed to each tick. However if the for loop fails on tick 1 out of 10, and the timer is waiting for 10 seconds, then the client will be informed after 10 seconds. However if the server was to impose a 1 second timeout for each tick (10x1sec = 10secs) then the client will be informed of timeout without having to wait the full 10 seconds.

Edit.

This whole client/server/timeout analogy is simply to put the question into context. I'm purely interested in the best way to time the for loop from a different thread.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by unreliable? If it times out randomly, that might just indicate that the work takes around 1 second and a significant number of the times the timeout is triggered (i.e. for a task that takes 0.8+-0.1 s you would expect ~1 in 50 to time out if the timeout is at 1 second), or that it does not time 1 second but sometimes times out the client after 0.1 second?

Comment: @RichardCritten The time out part is not part of the question. I'm simply interested in the best way to time each tick of the for loop. In my real problem it is not timing it out. I'm just trying to indicate that it is important to time the process.

Comment: This is an XY-problem the real problem is how is the client thread going to being notified / terminated?   If the client thread is notified to shut down then the client thread must be looping and polling (during the work) and it could shut itself down based on a timeout passed into it as part of the work-package.  If the client thread is hard looping (and not polling) then there is no way to cleanly shut down the client thread until it completes it's work.  Either way there is no need to monitor the client thread from the server thread.

Comment: @RichardCritten I'm simply trying to put the problem into context. There is no server or client involved in my real problem. The title reads "Best approach to Independently Timing each Tick of a For Loop in another Thread". I have clarified this in the question now.

Comment: You could implement a ledger, that receives a `std::chrono::time_point` each tick (and also after the entire loop), which would time each tick. You can make this ledger available to an other thread that periodically checks this, and sleeps so that it would wake when it expects the next entry, and when it doesn't it could set some flag, but I am not sure if this is the "Best" way. I also don't see the need for a different thread though.

Comment: @Lala5th Thanks for the suggestion. However the "client" thread performing the work can hang and therefore fail to time it self and take action if it does exceed the allowed time. Thus its necessary to perform the timing from a different thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this might be:

Shared vars:

```cpp
std::vector<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>> ledger;
std::mutex ledger_mtx;
```

Client:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    {
    std::scoped_lock lock(ledger_mtx);
    ledger.push_back(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now());
    }
    // Do work
}
{
std::scoped_lock lock(ledger_mtx);
ledger.push_back(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now());
}
```

Server:

```cpp
size_t id = 0;
std::this_thread::wait_for(1s); // Some time so that initial write to ledger is made
while(true) {
    {
    std::scoped_lock lock(ledger_mtx);
    if(ledger.size()==id) { /* Do something if the thread hangs */ }
    id = ledger.size();
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> last_tick = ledger.back();
    }
    if(id == 11) break;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s - (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - last_tick));
}
```

This way you can time the thread, while monitoring it from the outside. Is it the best way? probably not, but it does give you the times you need.

Comment: The problem starts with "_...Do something with a hung thread..."_ - as there is no way to cleanly terminate a hung or un-cooperative thread.  As the thread can't be terminated without leaving the process in an undefined state, timing the thread is pointless.  If the thread is co-operating (polling etc) there there is no need for timing it as the client thread can look after it's own timeout.

Comment: @RichardCritten I understand that, but OP says that _"This whole client/server/timeout analogy is simply to put the question into context. I'm purely interested in the best way to time the for loop from a different thread."_. Now why you would want this is beyond me as well. (Maybe to still get some benchmarking data even if thread hangs?). I phrased that comment badly, I meant to do something if thread hangs